# How to check if OS is 32 Bit OS or 64 Bit

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to check if computer is 32 bit or 64 using vb.net code?
I just want to display the result in a message.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you interested in knowing whether the OS is x86/x64 or whether your process is running as x86/x64?

Comment: Yes, that's an important ambiguity to clear up.  I'd say the question title and body are asking different things.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx) should do nicely.

> Determines whether the current operating system is a 64-bit operating system.

The assumption being that a false signifies a 32bit environment.

If you want to find out if the *process* is 64bit (as you can run a 32bit process on a 64bit OS), use [Environment.Is64BitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx):

> Determines whether the current process is a 64-bit process.

---

Both of these have been introduced in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Caveat: Only available from .NET 4.0

Comment: Good point to differentiate the *process* from the OS; there are many times that a 64-bit OS runs a 32-bit process.

Answer (score 1):

IntPtr.Size won't return the correct value if running in 32-bit .NET Framework 2.0 on 64-bit Windows (it would return 32-bit).

You have to first check if running in a 64-bit process (I think in .NET you can do so by checking IntPtr.Size), and if you are running in a 32-bit process, you still have to call the Win API function IsWow64Process. If this returns true, you are running in a 32-bit process on 64-bit Windows.

Microsoft's Raymond Chen:
[How to detect programmatically whether you are running on 64-bit Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/01/364563.aspx)

Solution:

```
Private is64BitProcess As Boolean = (IntPtr.Size = 8)
Private is64BitOperatingSystem As Boolean = is64BitProcess OrElse InternalCheckIsWow64()

<DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Winapi)> _
    Public Shared Function IsWow64Process( _
    ByVal hProcess As Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid, _
    ByRef wow64Process As Boolean) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean

    End Function

Public Shared Function InternalCheckIsWow64() As Boolean
    If (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major = 5 AndAlso Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 1) OrElse Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 Then
        Using p As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
            Dim retVal As Boolean
            If Not IsWow64Process(p.Handle, retVal) Then
                Return False
            End If
            Return retVal
        End Using
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: p.Handle is of type System.IntPtr whereas the expected type is Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid. How to fix this error ?

Comment: @MDLuffy - change `Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid` to `IntPtr`

Answer (score 1):

I simply use this piece of code and it works fine:

```
If System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem = True Then
    MessageBox.Show("OS System : 64 Bit Operating System")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("OS System : 32 Bit Operating System")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If IntPtr.Size = 8 Then

    ' 64 bit machine

ElseIf IntPtr.Size = 4 Then

    ' 32 bit machine

End If
```

Comment: Why is returning x32 while my machine is 64 bit?

Comment: It could be running in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit machine.  `IntPtr.Size` doesn't tell you about the architecture of the CPU (or the OS), but about the architecture for the code that is running.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET: What I wanted works as below. Define the custom constant `Win64` in x64 all configurations (debug, release etc), like in the diagram below, and use it as follows:

```
If (Win64) Then

   '64 bit code
else
   ' 32 bit code here
End If
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when u need .net 2 (to work around on all windows versions)
it has a very simple way to do it

```
 Function isit64() As Integer
        If Directory.Exists("c:\windows\syswow64") And Directory.Exists("c:\program files (x86)") Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
Msgbox (Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(IntPtr)) * 8)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
If System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)") Then
  MsgBox("64-Bit OS")
Else
  MsgBox("32-Bit OS")
End If
```

It will work on all the framework versions

Comment: Won't work if the Program Files directories are on a drive other than C:. Also won't work on a computer whose primary localization isn't English.