# Download and install sql server 2012 express 32bit as well as 64 bit without user interaction

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, express

I am trying  to download and install sql server 2012 express without users interaction . I have written vb.net code to download from microsoft site and then i need to pick up a file and run the setup without any user interaction.Code is extracting the exe at Temp folder then it is picking up the exe. But After extraction it is showing message box"extraction is complete" where i have to click ok button, bascically i dont want that interaction. Then I am not sure if it is installing the sql as I don't see any progress bar . i want complete silent installtion without a single interaction.

Can some body help me below is a Code.

```
 // Check the envionment

    If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem Then
        bittype = "64"
     Else
        bittype = "32"
    End If

//Download based on the bitSize


 If bittype = "32" Then
   wc.DownloadFile("https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/D/D/8DD7BDBA-  CEF7-4D8E-8C16-D9F69527F909/ENU/x86/SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe", "C:\Users\Sql   Server 2012.exe")
//code to run set up on 32 bit
else
Try
  wc.DownloadFile("https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/D/D/8DD7BDBA-CEF7-4D8E-8C16-D9F69527F909/ENU/x64/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe", "C:\Users\Sql Server 2012.exe")

 //code to run setup on 64 bit
//extracting at temp folder
 Dim ExtractDirectory As String = "c:/Users"
            'Dim ProcessProperties As New ProcessStartInfo
            'ProcessProperties.WorkingDirectory = "c:/Users"
            'ProcessProperties.FileName = "Sql Server 2012"
            'ProcessProperties.Arguments = "/extract:" + "C:/Users"
            'Dim extractProcess As Process =    Process.Start(ProcessProperties)
            'extractProcess.WaitForExit()

 //Run setup
Dim processObj2 As System.Diagnostics.Process =    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\Temp\setup.exe", "/QS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=TESTSQL /INSTANCEID=TESTSQL /INDICATEPROGRESS=""False""/IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""Local Service"" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""Local Service"" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=""Automatic""""/TCPENABLED=1 /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=""Automatic"" /AGTSVCACCOUNT=""Localservices"" /SKIPRULES=""RebootRequiredCheck""/SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=""test12345""")
            processObj2.WaitForExit()

 Catch ex As Exception
   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

Comment: See this for how to check if running 32 or 64 bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423057/how-to-check-if-os-is-32-bit-os-or-64-bit

Comment: I Have written that code !! Thanks

Comment: So then what part is not working, what error are you getting?

Comment: iNSTALLTION IS NOT WORKING